# Check MFA is enabled for a user using Azure Graph api

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Using   MS Graph API,
I want to check MFA is enabled for AD users or want to Get information of users registered with MFA
I tried this code but getting a ReferenceError: Window is not defined
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rvUb.png)
I am just want to get user data

```js
require("isomorphic-fetch");
const { UserAgentApplication } = require("msal");
const { ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider");
const { MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions");
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "bec52b71-dc94-4577-9f8d-b8536ed0e73d", // Client Id of the registered application
  },
};
const graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send"]; // An array of graph scopes

const msalApplication = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
const Options = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(graphScopes);

const authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(
  msalApplication,
  Options
);
const options = {
  authProvider,
};
const Client = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
const client = Client.init(options);
async function test() {
  try {
    let res = await client
      .api("/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails")
      .version("beta")
      .get();
    console.log("res: ", res);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
test();
```

Comment: The error is not related graph request, it states window not defined can you make sure the error is clear. please refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node) node.js using  graph

Comment: how do I  get the information of users registered with MFA?
Can you help me

Comment: Filter for users who are registered for MFA. For example: `/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=isMfaRegistered eq true`.Please let us know if it helps

Comment: The above code is not working how do I filter

Comment: The "window is not defined" error has been resolved? Please show how your code is currently. And what is the error now?

Comment: the error 'window is not defined' is has not been resolved

Comment: @Kainat Are you running this code in a console application?

Comment: No, I am running it on vs code